# Xamarin.İOS Hide Keyboard When Clicked Away

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I have a login page in my app which uses UITextField element. I want to hide the keyboard when I click away from that TextField.

I tried using this code that I saw on a website in my ViewDidLoad function but it didn't work.

```
EntryTextField.ShouldReturn = (textField) => 
{    
     textField.ResignFirstResponder();    
     return true;
};
```

Comment: generally the keyboard will hide when the text field loses focus

Comment: @Jason What do you mean by when text field loses focus? If you mean touching away from the text field, I tried that and it is not working.

Comment: when you "touch away" are you tapping another element like a button?  Or just some background element?

Comment: @Jason I am touching to the background element (View I guess)

Comment: I don't think that works.  If you don't tap on another element that can have focus, the cursor will remain in the Entry box and the keyboard will be active.  Apple's own apps behave this way.

Comment: @Jason I also tried to click other elements on the View (Label and a image box) and it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding these lines to ViewDidLoad():

```
        View.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(HideKyb);
        tapGesture.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        View.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);
```

and I added this line into the HideKyb function:

```
View.EndEditing(true);
```